# How do I create an api endpoint that needs authentication using jwt authentication for wp rest

Tags: php, wordpress, api

I have created an endpoint using the JWT api namespace, but cant seem to get the authentication part working, I have used wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token to gain access to a token, but then how do I authenticate the custom endpoint?

Below is some code and I have tried testing in postman but get several errors from 403 to No route was found matching the URL and request method

function wp_register_crm_routes() {

```
// register_rest_route() handles more arguments but we are going to stick to the basics for now.
register_rest_route( '/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1', 'addproduct', array(
    // By using this constant we ensure that when the WP_REST_Server changes our readable endpoints will work as intended.
    'methods'  =>'POST',
    // Here we register our callback. The callback is fired when this endpoint is matched by the WP_REST_Server class.
    'callback' => 'addProductFromCRM',
    'permission_callback' => function ($request) {
        if (current_user_can('edit_others_posts'))
        return true;
 }
) );
```

Answer (score -3):

Json web token requires 'secret key' to authenticate the API call. You can either generate it on a backend and pass it to frontend to use for every other subsequent api call or store it statically in environment variable at frontend (to be on safe side). (Optional) If you have a user signed in then you can attach the token to the user object as well.

Finally, you can verify that token in any of your protected routes.

## Javascript implementation

```
jwt.sign({user}, 'privatekey', { expiresIn: '1h' },(err, token) => {
            if(err) { console.log(err) }    
            res.send(token);
        });


jwt.verify(req.token, 'privatekey', (err, authorizedData) => {
        if(err){
            //If error send Forbidden (403)
            console.log('ERROR: Could not connect to the protected route');
            res.sendStatus(403);
        } else {
            //If token is successfully verified, we can send the autorized data 
            res.json({
                message: 'Successful log in',
                authorizedData
            });
            console.log('SUCCESS: Connected to protected route');
        }
    })
```

Comment: He tagged PHP, and it's safer to keep the secret key in the backend, not the frontend.

Comment: It was just an example to demonstrate. Since he didn't specified the PHP package in use, i just gave a JS implementation to get the abstract of solution.